# Eclipselink merge/persist with joined objects

Tags: java, jpa, insert, eclipselink

I have two entities, A and B.  When I merge A, I want B to be merged as well - so I never do operations on B, just always operations on A.  The B object will be accessible via the A object, but not vice versa (if possible).  A and B share the same primary key field, that is, the primary key field of B is a foreign key to the primary key of A.  However, I've finally got it to the point where the `INSERT` queries are in the correct order, but because it's not binding the ID in query parameters, it's throwing an `InsertNullViolation` as the primary key is not set.  Does anyone know how to get EclipseLink to bind the primary key for the joined objects like B?

```
public class A {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    public Long getA_ID();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", targetEntity = B.class)
    public B getB();
    ...
}

public class B {
    ...
    @Id
    public Long getA_ID();

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    public A getA();
    ...
}
```

The above setup does not set the primary key on B so throws an InsertNullViolation trying to insert into B.

```
public class A {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    public Long getA_ID();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", targetEntity = B.class)
    public B getB();
    ...
}

public class B {
    ...
    @Id
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    public A getA();
    ...
}
```

This setup also has the same issue.  The exception is:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SOME_USER"."B"."A_ID")

Error Code: 1400
Call: INSERT INTO B (SOME_FIELD1, SOME_FIELD2, ..., A_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ..., ?)
bind => [null, SOME_VALUE, ..., null]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(packagename.B@ObjectId)
```

That last `null` on the bind line needs to be filled in by EclipseLink with the actual ID that it previously retrieved from the sequence when it inserted object A. 
What I'm doing for merging boils down to essentially this:

```
public void merge(A objectA, B objectB) {
    objectA.setB(objectB);
    entitymanager.merge(objectA);
}
```

Comment: can you also show the code you are using to persist the entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are not setting the A on your B.

You must maintain bi-directional relationships, there is no magic that does this for you.

**When you create your A and assign the B you also must assign the A to the B, otherwise it is null, and will insert null.** Thus, you should be doing this instead:

```
public void merge(A objectA, B objectB) {
    A.setB(objectB); //so when you merge A it knows about the B objects
    B.setA(objectA); //so B knows to look at the A object for it's key
    entitymanager.merge(objectA);
}
```

Further, in your first example, you also have a duplicate A_ID field in B, so you must also set this value when setting the A of B. Ensure you have persisted A first, otherwise its Id will be null, you could avoid this by removing the A_ID and putting the @Id on the OneToOne as you have done in your second example.  You could also put insert/updateable=false in the A_ID and true in the OneToOne, then the foreign key value will come from the OneToOne.

You get the multiple writable mappings error because both the A_ID and the OneToOne map the same column, you need to mark one of them insert/updateable=false.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships

and,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.  I only thought I needed to set B on A for the merge to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation on [how to do it with Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5617). Since it's standard JPA, you should be able to do the same thing with EclipseLink.

Either you replace the A_ID in B with a mapped OneToOne association to A (and use `mappedBy` on the other side), or you keep the A_ID, but also add a OneToOne association to A and annotated it with `@MapsId` (and you also use `mappedBy` on the other side).

Comment: When I tried both of those examples I get `Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [B.A_ID]`

Comment: Yes, that's what the second example shows. Have you mapped the ID as a non-read-only ID?

Comment: When I removed some of the `updateable=false, insertable=false` and followed the `@MapsId` example I no longer got any exceptions, but it still tried to insert B before A and failed.  Do you have an example by of `mappedBy`?  Ideally, there is no join in B to A, as that method `getA()` will never be called.  I just want the method `getB()` on A.  I'm also annotating the methods instead of the fields - will that cause an issue, or should work the same correct? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Done.  Still need `updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false` on the `getB()` method otherwise you get a `multiple mappings exist` error.

Comment: That's what I suspected. You're mapping the same bidirectional association twice: once in A, and once in B. Each time you specify the same join column or join table twice, there is a problem somewhere. As I said in my answer, the association A.getB() must be the inverse of the association `B.getA()`, with the `mappedBy` attribute: `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true) public B getB()`

Comment: Thanks for your help JB.  That answer helped me get the EOs setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I been doing em.persist(parent), even when I been doing parent.setChildren(child). So I had to add child.setParent(parent). But it's relative to the entity you are persisting because you also can do em.persist(child). For brevity, try to set the relation in both entities.

An extra comment, when I did what I'm telling in the previous lines then I got an "ORA-02291" error, having an inconsistence with my foreign key. It was due that I had a TRIGGER to set up the PK of my table and I was also using @SequenceGenerator in my entity. To solve this, I had to validate in my TRIGGER that only the PK can be set up to MYSEQUENCE.nexval if :new.PK_TABLE is null.

Hope this could help someone with the same trouble because I was stuck with this problem since yesterday and it was too much wasting of time.